# Is it possible to call a method from a field value in an annotation?

Tags: java

Is something like this possible in java? I couldn't find reference/docs to it anywhere. `someMethod()` should return a string.

```
@MyAnnotation(value="someMethod()")
public class Blah{

}
```

Comment: The annotation value here is just a string literal.  It's possible that a particular library that processes certain annotations may try to parse the literal and evaluate it.  Spring supports some annotations with `method()` inside string literals.  But that's part of those libraries, not part of Java.

Answer (score 4):

Annotation value should be a  compile time constant. You cannot have a dynamic value.